# How do I receive notifications when TextKit's NSTextContainer's size changes?

Tags: textkit

I need to know when `TextKit`'s `NSTextContainer`'s `size` changes, so I can update some caches in my `NSLayoutManager`. How can I receive notifications when `size` changes? Does `TextKit` in general (and `NSTextContainer`'s `size` property specifically) support KVO? I reviewed the `NSTextContainer.h` header and the [`NSTextContainer` documetation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSTextContainer_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/NSTextContainer), and I can't find anything about it either way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`NSTextContainer` is supposed to call [`-[NSLayoutManager textContainerChangedGeometry:]`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSLayoutManager_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSLayoutManager/textContainerChangedGeometry:) on its `NSLayoutManager` when its size or shape changes:

> This method is invoked automatically by other components of the text
>   system; you should rarely need to invoke it directly. Subclasses of
>   NSTextContainer, however, must invoke this method any time their size
>   of shape changes (a text container that dynamically adjusts its shape
>   to wrap text around placed graphics, for example, must do so when a
>   graphic is added, moved, or removed).

I haven't tested this to determine if it requires that `heightTracksTextView` or `widthTracksTextView` be set on the `NSTextContainer`; that `verticallyResizable` or `horizontallyResizable` be set on the `NSLayoutManager`; or that programmatically calling `-[NSTextContainer setSize:]` or `-[NSTextContainer setSimpleRectangularTextContainer:]` will automatically call `-[NSLayoutManager textContainerChangedGeometry:]` as advertised.